# Property as a list or array in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use LOAD CSV for data ingestion in neo4j.Let's say there are two different CSVs which have data for same nodetype and both the CSVs have data for same properties but the value of the property in first CSV is getting overwritten by value of property in second CSV.

Is there away in neo4j where the values of properties can be stored as a List or an Array without getting overwritten.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ON CREATE and ON MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match) subclauses of [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) to either create or append to a list property, like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS line
MERGE (f:Foo {id: line.id})
ON CREATE SET f.bar = [line.prop]
ON MATCH SET f.bar = f.bar + line.prop
```

Comment: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
throws above error 
`USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row WITH row MATCH (application:Application {  name:row.ApplicationName   })MATCH (program:Program {  name:row.ProgramName   })MERGE (application)-[r:HAS]->(program) ON CREATE SET   r.attr1 = [row.COLUMN1]  ON MATCH SET   r.attr1 = r.attr1 + row.COLUMN1  ;`

Comment: The value of `row.COLUMN1` must be a primitive type (because node/relationship properties must be primitive types or arrays thereof). See the table [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/property-values/) for a (partial) list of primitive types. For instance, a property value cannot be a map, a multi-level array, or an array of maps, a map of maps, etc.